# How to integrate OpenStreetMap into a react-native project?

Tags: android, ios, react-native, mapbox, openstreetmap

I am trying to integrate OpenStreetMap into a React Native project. But I can't find any library or anything related to React Native in [their GitHub account](https://github.com/openstreetmap).

The only thing I can find relating to these to topics is the link below, in which there is no proper answer.

https://www.reddit.com/r/reactnative/comments/5fi6bg/how_to_add_openstreetmap_to_a_react_native_project/

But I heard once that Mapbox uses OpenStreetMap as their source. Mapbox suggests a good way to integrate it into a React Native project:

https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl

Is there a way to integrate OpenStreetMap into a React Native project
or is it the case there's not proper support for it yet.

Comment: Did you get any clue or code how to integrate open maps in react native?

Comment: Nope, I had to use mapbox instead. Because mapbox uses OpenStreetMap

Comment: Do you have to pay for mapbox? Are there any limits? Could it be used for businesses?

Comment: yes, if you are planning to commercialise it you will have to pay for it.The packages are shown in their website.

Comment: I believe the standard [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps) package does the job you want done?

Comment: Hey @Amalp are u solve this?

Comment: @DevAS  No man. I don't know if any implementations has been introduced its been a while i touched react native if you find something post an answer.

Comment: Sadly.. if u play with Mapbox check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59266242/directions-between-two-point-location-in-mapbox-gl-react-native) please

Answer (score 14):

## Using Mapbox GL

> ⚠️ **WARNING:** the instructions below for Mapbox appear to no longer be free if you use SDK/library versions after 2.0.0, released around Dec 2020. See this SO answer for more details: https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/188241/55948

**Old answer (pre-December 2020 - see above):**

Another option is to use [Mapbox GL](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps), which is free as long as you don't use anything in the Mapbox *platform*. Unlike other options, this won't require an API key ([[source 1]](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/mapbox-sdk-is-it-free-if-you-host-your-own-vector-tiles) [[source 2]](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57251504/use-mapbox-gl-js-without-access-token)).

There's often confusion about Mapbox, since the platform (global styles, tilesets, datasets, Mapbox Studio, etc) is paid, but Mapbox GL is a library which you may use to display content that is either self-hosted or hosted by the Mapbox platform.

Below is an snippet [of an example](https://github.com/react-native-mapbox-gl/maps/blob/master/example/src/examples/WatercolorRasterTiles.js) using [Stamen Watercolor tiles](http://maps.stamen.com/) (which are also OSM-based):

```
render() {
  const rasterSourceProps = {
    id: 'stamenWatercolorSource',
    tileUrlTemplates: [
      'https://stamen-tiles.a.ssl.fastly.net/watercolor/{z}/{x}/{y}.jpg',
    ],
    tileSize: 256,
  };

  return (
    <MapboxGL.MapView style={sheet.matchParent}>
      <MapboxGL.Camera
        zoomLevel={16}
      />

      <MapboxGL.RasterSource {...rasterSourceProps}>
        <MapboxGL.RasterLayer
          id="stamenWatercolorLayer"
          sourceID="stamenWatercolorSource"
          style={{rasterOpacity: this.state.opacity}}
        />
      </MapboxGL.RasterSource>
    </MapboxGL.MapView>
  );
}
```

## Other options

As mentioned earlier, one other option for React Native (both Android and iOS) is [react-native-maps](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-maps).

It's at best *unclear*, though, if you must use a Google API key to use this lib if you don't display a Google map: Google says [*"To use the Maps SDK for Android you must have an API key"*](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android-sdk/get-api-key), but `react-native-maps` appears to use a drop-in Maps SDK replacement called [AirMapView](https://airbnb.io/AirMapView/), which supports other providers and claims you'd need to setup the native Maps SDK on Android only "to support native Google Maps". To be on the safe side, most people end up setting up a billing account with Google to generate an API key (even if you don't plan to ever count a single map view), something which Mapbox doesn't require.

Comment: Mapbox switched to a non-OSS license in December 2020 https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/188141/mapbox-sdk-is-it-free-if-you-host-your-own-vector-tiles

Answer (score 11):

You can use a custom Tile Overlay (OpenStreetMap too) in `react-native-maps` package: https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps

(scroll to **Using a custom Tile Overlay** section)

You need to add api key. You don't need to use Maps API at all and the key won't be used in that case.

Comment: I tried this library but why it needs google map API key? i'm using custom OSM tile server!

Comment: So this is basically still using google map api key right?

Comment: @OliverD just set a google API key but don't let render google tiles.
Also you can change canvas padding or margin to hide google logo.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi sadly google does not accept my client visa card so I can't get the key :( and I don't know how can i handle it without the key or google maps services

Comment: @OliverD just create a free token in google maps. You will not render the google tiles, So you are not worry to overload free token.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi To create it google need a visa card to ensure I'm not a robot :))

Comment: @OliverD Are you sure? I did generate many free tokens just using my google account without any verification. Is this new policy? let me check that.

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi Yeah check [this](https://developers.google.com/maps/gmp-get-started)  in billing account section

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi are u check it?

Comment: @OliverD if you need key for development only send me a message on telegram messenger then i send you one of my keys. my telegram id: @ elMarian

Comment: @VahidAlimohamadi Thank u very much, I appreciate that... I just add my credit card and got one for my client :D

Comment: Not relevant anymore because of https://github.com/react-native-maps/react-native-maps/pull/2348#issuecomment-809502618