# OpenStreetMap integration in React-Native

Tags: react-native, openstreetmap, react-native-maps, react-native-mapbox-gl

I have a requirement of creating maps in react native. the requirements are as follows:

- Only use use OpenStreetMap API's
- Implement Dark Mode
- The screens to be developed are -
- [image: screen 1]
- [image: screen 2]

I found there are 2 library's. react-native-maps and mapbox-gl. I read that react-native-maps user google-maps as provider . So in my case it will be not feasible as I have to use only OpenStreetMap provide.

Can anyone suggest me is there any other library where i can show such maps which in-turn should be using OpenStreetMap provider?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out the StackOverflow Discussion, which might help you with your query.

[How to integrate OpenStreetMap into a react-native project?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48885200/how-to-integrate-openstreetmap-into-a-react-native-project)

Comment: Thank you Jignesh. It really helped.